# Debug/Release configuration influence on compiled binary

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have application myApp.exe that is using myDll.dll . Dll is compiled in `Release` mode. myQApp.exe is running in `Debug` configuration mode. During myDll.dll function call exception is rised:

```
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in myApp.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in myApp.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while myApp.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.
```

When I place dll that is compiled with Debug configuration everything goes fine. Should I look for some bugs in code or Debug/Release modes can make influence on this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite common for an object definition to be different in debug and release modes. So if you pass such an object from a debug module to a release module errors are no surprise. It does not mean you have a bug.